# failed to use urllib.request with python in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I tried to import urllib.request wth python in vscode but kept getting the message: ImportError: No module named request. I have no problem importing just urllib, which I know is the right line for python2. I'm sure I'm using python3 as that's what I've selected in the interpreter path.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

I've also put pip3 install urllib3 in the terminal and got this message which means python3 should have it:

Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.26.9)

any idea what have gone wrong or it's not the problem with python version?

Comment: `urllib.request` and `urllib3.request` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your multiple environments. You should specify the installation path when using pip installation package.

```
pip install -t flodername urllib3 #the package of the python interpreter you chosen
```